# how to rename a field in a JsonNode using jackson API

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JsonNode with this JSON in it :

```
{"temperature":17,"long":200,"lat":100}
```

I want to change the JsonNode to look like this

```
{"MyNewFieldName":17,"long":200,"lat":100}
```

Is it possible using Jackson API ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You won't be able to rename keys in key-value JSON pairs. What you will need to do is create a new key-value pair with the same value but with a different key and remove the old one.

```
JsonNode node = ...;
ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) node;
object.set("MyNewFieldName", node.get("temperature"));
object.remove("temperature");
```