# Convert two type of json to the same object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm writing a framework for a web service api that return json. I use Jackson library to deserialize the json string. The api return a property to continue fetching the result of request. The response like this:

```
{
    continueToken:"token",
    results: [ 
                {
                },
             ]
}
```

All the responses have this structure. The only problem is that the name of the continue property differ from request to another. The name is like this

```
prefix + "continue"
```

I want to create only one class and to be able to map the json to this class. How can I do that? Here's what I want to have:

```
public class Response {
    private String continueToken;
    private List<Article> results;

    public Response (String continueToken, Article[] articles) {
         this.continueToken = continueToken;
         this.results = Arrays.asList(articles);
    }
}
//Here the name is ttcontinue
String json = request.get(type1);
Response r = jsonToResponse(json);

//Here the name is llcontinue
json = request.get(type2);
r = jsonToResponse(json);
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. So all responses have the `continueToken` variable but the requests have a different variable name in which to pass the `continueToken` ? Could you not take the token from the response and pass it into the right variable on the request and then serialize to json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm.. you have a dynamic field name, annotation solutions cannot work. Assuming there is no other JSON field ending in "continue" (which holds in your example), you can follow these steps:

1. Iterate over the JSON keys as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760138/parsing-json-in-java-without-knowing-json-format)
2. Use `field.getKey().endsWith("continue")` to find your desired key
3. Replace the key in your JSON node using code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151398/how-to-rename-a-field-in-a-jsonnode-using-jackson-api) with `"continueToken"`
4. Now get your `Response` object